# Mail Merge with Open Office from C# .NET

Tags: c#, openoffice.org, mailmerge, openoffice-writer

I need to be able to mail merge from an ASP.NET web form in C# .net to Open Office.  I can connect with OpenOffice and open a file but that is where things stop at the moment.  I have a table of mail merge items that need inserting into a document for each client on my system but I can't find anything on the internet that helps me perform the mail merge or even how to set the mail merge up.

If anyone can show me a simple example merging forenames and surnames out of a database table into an Open Office mail merge form using C#, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I have worked invoking Open Office libraries from C# even using the writer from a form( or dialog), but I don't know what's the Open Office mail merge. Could you explain me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking in the [Open Office Forum for Code Snippets](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewforum.phtml?f=11). There are a lot of C#-examples and if you don't find something you can use, I would propose to post the question there (if you haven't already).

Documentation about MailMerge-Datasources is [here](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/MailMerge.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may find [AODL ODF Toolkit](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/AODL) useful. I use extensively the Java version to manipulate ODTs.